# Breaking out of while loop by input-unintended reverts to previous iteration Python

Tags: python, while-loop, break

I am learning python and took up a suggested idea to try and make a hangman program. I have been messing around for a day or two and I have the main meat of the code working. It works on either 1 player or 2 player. 1 player chooses a random word, and 2 player takes a word/phrase from a user.

Everything functions as I expect, except for the way my break is working. If someone reaches 6/6 strikes, it asks them if they want to play again. If they play again, it all works. If they say no the first time, it works as intended. However, if they play again and lose again, if they input "no" they don't want to play again, it will continue asking them if they want to play again. It will ask for each previous state they answered yes to.

Example:
They fail, it tells them "your word was pie. play again?" yes
they fail, it tells them "your word was elephant. play again?" no
                         "your word was pie. play again?"

So they must say no for every stage they encounter. It works exactly the same issue in 1p or 2p. I know I most likely have an inefficient system, but I can show the code for the 1player case for help to remedy this.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import random

def playhangman():

    print('At any time, type "stop" to stop playing')
    print('1 player- you guess a random word. Random difficulty.')
    print('2 player- you type a word/phrase and your friend guesses.')
    playerdecision = input('Would you to play 1 or 2 player? (1p/2p):')

    if playerdecision =='1p':
        list_of_words = pd.read_csv('hangmanwords.txt')              #entire list of words as a df
        list_of_words = list_of_words.values.tolist()           #entire list of words as a list
        rand_word = random.choice(list_of_words)                #now have a single random word 1 element list

        rand_word = list(rand_word)                             #separates each letter of random word
        listedrandword = list(rand_word[0])
        listedrandword = [x.lower() for x in listedrandword]    #makes everything lowercase

        df = pd.DataFrame(listedrandword).T                     #1 by n vector instead of n by 1

        df = df.replace(r'^\s*$', np.nan, regex=True)           #replaces spaces/white space as nan
        df.fillna(0, inplace=True)                              #fills nan with 0s

        for letter in df:                                       #sets 0's to spaces to every other letter or symbol can be blanket-swapped
            if df.iloc[0,letter] == 0:
                df[letter]=' '
            elif df.iloc[0,letter] == '.':
                df[letter]='.' 
            else:
                df[letter] = '_'
        print(df)

        count=0

        while count < 6:
            letterguess = input('What letter would you like to guess? :').lower()   #makes sure inputs are regarded as lowercase
            if any(letterguess in word for word in listedrandword)==1:
                qq = [i for i,x in enumerate(listedrandword) if x == letterguess]
                for j in qq:
                    df[j] = letterguess
                print(' ')
                print(df)
                print(' ')

            elif letterguess == 'stop':
                count=7

            else:
                print('Sorry, that is wrong. This is strike',(count+1),'/6')
                count = count+1
                print('')
                print(df)
                print('')
            if df.values.tolist()[0] == listedrandword:
                print('You saved Bob! You win!')
                checker = input('Would you like to play again? (y/n)')
                if checker == 'y':
                    playhangman()
                elif checker == 'n':
                    print('Goodbye.')
                    count = 7
                else:
                    print('y/n not detected. Please type "y" or "n".')



        while count == 6:
            print('You lose, and Bob has died. The correct word was', rand_word)
            checker = input('Would you like to play again? (y/n)').lower()
            if checker == 'y':
                playhangman()
            elif checker == 'n':
                print('Goodbye.')
                count = 7
                break
            else:
                print('y/n not detected. Please only use "y" or "n".')
                break

    #need to loop this 1p still, reset counter, clear random word


    #omitted if playerdecision=='2p'
    return
playhangman()
```

Since the "no" cases change count =7, it leaves and exits since the while's don't account for anything bigger than 6. I don't understand why it jumps back to everything else played in one sitting.

Comment: It’s a recursive function. It calls itself. Does the problem happen after the recursive call has happened? (I.e print something after your call to "playhangman()" and see what happens next. Maybe you need returns at the end rather than breaks?

Comment: You call "playhangman" inside of "playhangman" (so-called "recursion"). The new call has its own memory for all local variables like e. g. "count" and when the inner function call returns the new values are thrown away and the previous values the outer call had when the inner call started are used again.

Comment: I understand what you're saying, I see why it is happening now. I tried changing it to return though and it is the same problem. Is there a way to get the desired "recursion" of it playing again based on yes, but only needing one "no" to completely "break out" of the game?

Comment: Possible solution: Avoid recursion and create one function which only plays the game once and returns. Create another function with a while loop which calls the first function, then asks if player wants to play again and then either breaks the loop or iterates through it again depending on the answer.

Comment: Thank you. I went ahead and tried doing that, and I got everything up and running like I was wanting, now without the recursion problem. Couple of people pointed out my problem, but this gave me a way to fix it. Helpful and understanding=)

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to ditch this nasty pattern that a lot of new programmers seem to adopt for some reason. The pattern goes like this: I'm making a simple game and wrapping it entirely in one single function. When the player loses or wins, I want to ask them if they'd like to play again. If they say yes, **I call the game function again so they can play again**.

That's a BIG no-no. You'll want to use a loop instead - every time you are calling your game function you are pushing a new active subroutine on the call stack. Just because you are calling the function again doesn't mean the previous subroutine becomes inactive and just goes away - or something like that. When the inner subroutine ends, execution will return to the caller - but in your case it is unlikely to end, since you are not only committing this crime once, but twice, AND each time in a separate while loop. Big ooof.

There's nothing wrong with recursion (a function calling itself) - but it should only be used **deliberately** (in other words, if you know what you're doing).

Take a look at my simple game, which mimics the structure of your code more or less:

```
def start_game():
    print("Hello, welcome to my game!")
    print("Oops, you lost! Want to play again?")

    user_input = input()

    if user_input == "yes":
        start_game()

    print("When does this happen?")

start_game()
```

Output:

```
Hello, welcome to my game!
Oops, you lost! Want to play again?
yes
Hello, welcome to my game!
Oops, you lost! Want to play again?
yes
Hello, welcome to my game!
Oops, you lost! Want to play again?
yes
Hello, welcome to my game!
Oops, you lost! Want to play again?
yes
Hello, welcome to my game!
Oops, you lost! Want to play again?
no
When does this happen?
When does this happen?
When does this happen?
When does this happen?
When does this happen?
>>>
```

I'm almost certain that you weren't expecting this output. Again, just because you call your game function to simulate a new game, does not mean the current / previous active subroutines just evaporate. They are patiently waiting on the call stack until execution comes back to them and they can finish their job(s). Not only is this obviously undesirable in your case, but it's error-prone, too. For any game that you write using this structure I can give you an input that will raise a `RecursionError` exception.